# RealityKit's equivalent of SceneKit's SCNShape

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, scenekit, realitykit

On SceneKit, using `SCNShape` we can create SCN geometry from SwiftUI 2D shapes/beziers:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnshape

Is there an equivalent in RealityKit? Could we use the `generate(from:)` for that?
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/meshresource/3768520-generate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In RealityKit 2.0 you can generate a mesh using [MeshDescriptor](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/meshdescriptor). There is no support for two-dimensional path at the moment, like it's implemented in SceneKit.

```
var descriptor = MeshDescriptor(name: "anything")
descriptor.primitives = .triangles(indices)
let mesh: MeshResource = try! .generate(from: [descriptor])
```